# Layout text vertically so the text orientation is upright

Tags: swiftui

I would like to have text placed vertically on top of an image, so the text is displayed upright. I have written code to do that, but it feels like a hack. I am hoping someone has a better way to do this. My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct VerticalText: View {
  let input = "12.4"
  let myFont = Font.system(size: 22.0).bold()
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow).frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
      getText()
    }
  }
  
  func getText() -> some View {
    let chars = input.map { String($0) }
    return VStack {
      ForEach(chars, id: \.self) { char in
        if char == "." {
          Text(char)
            .font(myFont)
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 2, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: 0.0, y: -6.0)
        }else {
          Text(char)
            .font(myFont)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct VerticalText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VerticalText()
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- I've replaced the image with a rectangle and simplified the input to a constant for the purposes of this question.
- The input will be a number between 0 and 100. There may optionally be up to two decimal places.
- The if block for the "." is there to tighten up the spacing when the input is a decimal number. Without it the result looks like:

[image: yellow rectangle with 12.4 displayed vertically. There is a large gap between the 2 and the decimal]

In the above image, there is a rather large gap between the 2 and the decimal. I want to shrink that space. To do that I set the frame size on the decimal. This results in:

[image: yellow rectangle with 12.4 displayed vertically. There gap between the 2 and the decimal is reduced]

However, the above code feels like a hack. The offset is hard coded and the if statement feels wrong. Is there a better way to layout text vertically?

Comment: I don't believe there is a native way in SwiftUI to do this. I'd stick with your solution, but maybe recommend using .padding(.bottom, 3) instead of an offset.

Comment: OK, I will try with the padding instead. Thank you @nicksarno